# How to extract the value from a resultset of two statements that are union

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I have a method in dao class called ***"getDetails"***. In this method, I union the two select statements from two tables with almost same field called ***"main shop"*** & ***"sub shops"*** and put those queries to preparedstatement. Then I put the preparedStatement to resultSet.

This ***"getDetials"*** method return ***"details"*** and I'll use it into another method in mediator called ***"writefile"*** in order to print the values in microsoft word like ***"writefile(details)"***. In the ***"writefile"*** method, there are strings of values and put the values of "details" to respective string. And append the ***"outputString"*** for each value.

On the input screen, user may check ***"sub shops"*** check box and will fill the details of ***"sub shops"*** after checking it. If they don't check, they need to fill only ***"main details"*** and not ***"sub shops"***. If they check ***"main shop"***, I need to print only one letter. If they check ***"sub shops"*** and fill the ***"quantity of sub shops"***, I need to print the letters where the letter number is equal to ***"quantity of subshops"*** + one(main letter). The letter format is totally same but only change the value of the fields of ***"shop name"*** (main or sub shop), ***"shop bank code"*** (main or sub shop) according to user's choice.

In the mediator, I loop the ***"writefile(details)"*** according to  the quantity of ***"sub shops"***.

The problem is the data in different letters are same (only show the ***"main shop"*** data) though the letter quanity is correct (eg. if there are two ***"sub shops"***, it prints three letters). How should I do to get the value of ***"sub shops"*** in subsequent letters after ***"main shop"*** letter is printed.

This is "writefile" method

```
if(flag){
this.getHeading();
StringBuffer outputString = new StringBuffer();
Date date = new Date();
 SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM,yyyy");
          String dateString=formatter.format(date);
          details.sysDate =dateString;
          String date1=(String)details.getSysDate();

if(details.getNo() != null){
no=details.getNo();
}else {no=" ";}
if(details.bankName() != null){
bname=details.getBankName();
}else {bname = " ";}

outputString.append('\"');
outputString.append(date1);
outputString.append('\"');
outputString.append(",");
outputString.append('\"');
outputString.append(no);
outputString.append('\"');
outputString.append(",");
outputString.append('\"');
outputString.append(bname);
outputString.append('\"');
outputString.append(",");
outputString.append('\"');

dos.writeBytes(outputString.toString());
dos.flush();
dos.close();
fos.close();
}
```

The query sample is

```
    public Details getDetails (String No, String LoginID, String LetterID)
    {
        connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
                StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
                query.append("select TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'DD MONTH,YYYY'),a.no, b.bank_name");
                query.append("from t_newappl a,t_newappl_bank b where b.no = a.no and a.no=(select no from t_newappl whereno=?) and rownum=1 and status = 'PEND'");
                query.append(" union all ");
                query.append("select TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'DD MONTH,YYYY'),a.no,b.bank_name");
                query.append("from t_newappl a,t_newappl_bank b, newappl_sub c, t_newappl_sub_bank d where a.no = c.no and c.sub_id= d.sub_id and a.no=(select no from t_newappl where no=?) and rownum=1 and d.status = 'SPEND'");
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query.toString());
                preparedStatement.setString(1,ApplicationNo);
                preparedStatement.setString(2,ApplicationNo);
                ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                while (resultSet.next()){
                   Details = new BankDetails();
                    Details.No= Util.Trim(resultSet.getString("NO"));
                    Details.BankName= Util.Trim(resultSet.getString("BANK_NAME"));          

                }

                resultSet.close();
                preparedStatement.close();

        return Details;
}
```

The looping to print letter is

```
    int retail = Outletht.size();
                                            int ctr = 0;
                                             for (int i = 1; i <= subshop.size ; i++ ){
                                                  ctr++;
                                                  Letter Letter = new Letter(lmediator);
                                                 BankDetails Details = Letter.printLetter(applicationNumber);
                                                  if (Details!=null){
                                                    if (ctr == 1) {
                                                        if ((Details.getNo() == null)
                                                                && (Details.getLetterID() == null)
                                                                && ((Details.getLoginID() == null) || (Details.getLoginID().equals("")))) {
                                                        } else {
                                                            Letter.databaseUpdate(Details);
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                                     Letter.writefile(Details);                                            
                                                  Letter.callfile(Details);
                                                  context.showMessage("I01015");                                                     

                                                    }                                         
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    context.showMessage("I04004");
                                                }
                        }
```

Comment: Can you give some sample code also.... it will be easier to see... most probably you are passing wrong data to the `writefile` method...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to follow.  Some sample query output may help clarify.

If you're having trouble distinguishing the difference between main and sub records, i would suggest you add a column to your query before the union.

select A, B, 'main' as xtype from T1
union all
select A, B, 'sub' as xtype from T2

```
A    B    xtype
---  ---  ---
aaa  bbb  main
bbb  ccc  sub
```